# token URL can't find

Tags: actions-on-google

I have some problems with the Account Linking for Google Actions
I have implemented the OAuth2 steps described in the documentation by Google. 
I have found out the client id and client secrete also authenticate my URL, but now I am stuck  in token URL,  what should I do in my PHP application that finds token, I am new to this I use web application to connect to smart home action

[image]

Comment: You should spend some time reading about OAuth, as it doesn't seem like your authorization URL is correct either

Comment: please suggest me a good tutorial I read much but still, I am not clear

Comment: I'd suggest looking at a service like Auth0 to handle authorization for you.

Comment: I am now able to know to authorization concept but access token exchange??

Comment: OAuth is something that needs to be very secure, and if you're unsure of how to do it, you should rely on a third-party service.